# Overflow Error evaluating arithmetic expression with integers in VBA

Tags: vba

The following evaluates to `32760`, an integer:

```
Debug.Print (20 * 1638 - 1)
```

But this raises an overflow error:

```
Dim t as Integer
t = 1639
Debug.Print (20 * t - 1)
```

It seems like this is implicitly expecting an `Integer` return value, because if I do either of the following, the error is avoided.

`Dim t as Long` OR `Debug.print (20 * CLng(t) - 1)` OR `Debug.Print (20# * t - 1)`

Is this behavior documented?

Is my assumption accurate? Namely, that arithmetic of integers implies an integer return value, and that simply introducing one `Long` or `Double` value in to the equation will avoid the error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301733/vba-what-is-97-45-1

Comment: That's an excellent answer you linked to, thanks @TimWilliams.

Comment: Useful for me too...

Comment: It may also be worth noting that VBA converts all `Integer` values to `Long` type, so there isn't  any real benefits (which I can think of) in using `Integer` over  `Long`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164506(v=office.10).aspx

Comment: Now I'm confused - if VBA converts Integer to Long as the article suggests, then why would an overflow occur for values outside of a 16 bit boundary?

Comment: @SOofWXLS AFAIK it's an internal conversion to long data type, if you try to put that result in to a typed variable `as Integer`, an overflow results. For my OP here, when doing math operations on *all* integer type data, VBA assumes the implied result is also `Integer`. It is quirky in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my logic is correct, `Dim` or 'Dimension' is a way of telling the application that you expect use a variable of a certain type, and that type pertains to a certain amount of 'bits' (of memory).

This reserves a section of the system's memory, which has been allocated a certain amount of bits dependant on the variable type that you have instructed in your code. These bits then define how many  (If you're familiar with C++ or similar then you will probably already know all this...)

An Integer is 16 bits in VBA and is a *signed* integer which means we can store negative values too, so the limit is 32,767 because this is the biggest number we can achieve with 16 bits:

(generally a variable can hold 2^n where n = number of bits)

---

```
unsigned 16 bits =         0 - 65,536    (2^16)
signed 16 bits   =   -32,768 - 32,767
32,767           =    111111111111111    (Binary)
32,768           =    1000000000000000 <--- note the extra bit
```

---

This extra bit is what causes the "overflow" error - because the amount of bits required to produce the number *overflows* the amount of bits that the memory has to store the number safely.

I don't think the method of the calculation is documented to this extent, however your code snippet:

```
Dim t as Integer
t = 1639
Debug.Print (20 * t - 1)
```

would require `t` to be first be multiplied by 20, resulting in a figure of 32,780:

```
20 * t = 20 * 1639 = 32,780
32,780 = 1000000000001100 (Binary)
```

which overflows the bit limit for the `Integer` data type. At this point the system throws an error before it has the chance to proceed with the rest of the calculation because it tries to multiply `t` *whilst still in it's allocated memory address*, for which only 16 bits of memory have been reserved.

Also, not declaring `t` as a type will force VBA to default to type `Variant` which will assess that `t` needs to have more memory allocated when the calculation runs and push it into the `Long` boundary automatically.

---

**Update:** It would appear that VBA will only permit the highest amount of bits held by a variable within the equation for the return value, as can be seen in this example:

```
Sub SO()

Dim t As Integer, c As Long

t = 1639
c = 20

Debug.Print (20 * (t - 1))  '// No Error
Debug.Print (c * (t - 1))   '// No Error
Debug.Print ((c * t) - 1)   '// No Error

c = (20 * t - 1)            '// Error
Debug.Print (20 * t - 1)    '// Error

End Sub
```

Although I don't believe this is documented anywhere, it would lead one to believe that VBA limits memory usage to the highest amount of bits being used by a variable at any one time.

Comment: @David Zemens I fully appreciate with a rep of 21k+ you will already know most of this - it's mainly for the benefit of the VBA community that aren't as 'clued up' on memory allocation and OOP.

Comment: +1 all very good information! It doesn't answer the question per se (i know why a long causes an overflow in an integer, but wasnt sure why certain arithmetic would cause an overflow independent of a type container, i.e., multiplying an integer x integer implies an integer output even if assigning the result to a property capable of accepting a Long!) but should still be useful for others with similar q's in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidZemens I've added some more onto my answer after playing around some more, I think ultimately without any official documentation all we can do is make 'educated guesses' at what the reason is. VERY interesting though so I hope some more information comes to light - good question!

Comment: You've got too many parentheses in the Debug statements  or, you've put parentheses in such a way that changes the order of operations: `(20 * t - 1)` == `((20 * t) - 1)`., `(20 * t - 1)` will throw an error, because of the implied output type as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301733/vba-what-is-97-45-1). The issue is that the product of an expression consisting only of integers can potentially cause an overflow even if assigning to a Long/Double container, because the implied output will be of type `Integer` -- try it: `Dim val as Long: val = (20 * 1639 * 1)`.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that - I think I just misunderstood the question and went on a bit of a tangent, oops!