# VBA If statement Issue

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm using a userform with four text-boxes for users to enter numeric values that must amount (across the four inputs) to a total of 1.

I'm then using those values in conjunction with cell values to perform a calculation. In order to try and stop users from entering cumulative values of less than or greater than 1 I'm using the following If statement to be executed upon clicking the 'OK' button of the user form.

However, the Then Statement (display MsgBox and exit sub) even if the values to amount to 1. Whatever the values are, the If Statement is found to be true. Any ideas?

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()
If DirectorBox.Value + SnrBox.Value + MngrBox.Value + ResearcherBox.Value <> 1 Then
    MsgBox "Values must amount to a total of 1"
    Exit Sub
End If
Sheets("Menu").Range("G13").Value = (Range("G9").Value * DirectorBox.Value) _
+ (Range("G10").Value * SnrBox.Value) + (Range("G11").Value * MngrBox.Value) _
+ (Range("G12").Value * ResearcherBox.Value)
Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

Comment: The message says they must amount to 100 but you are testing if they equal 1. Which is it?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. My intention is 1; I was just varying the value to see if it made a difference when I copied the code (it didn't).

Comment: Anything you enter into text boxes is considered text so you have to format it to get it as a number Format(Val(DirectorBox.Value) + Val(SnrBox.Value) + Val(MngrBox.Value) + Val(ResearcherBox.Value))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Textboxes hold text, not just numbers, so the data type of the `Value` property is a string.

Your test on the If line is doing a string concatenation not a numeric addition so the value can never be equal to a numeric 1.

You need to convert the textual representation of the numbers that are in the textboxes to actual numbers. Assuming that the values being entered are fractional numbers, this should work:

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()
dim checkVal As Double
If IsNumeric(DirectorBox.Value) Then checkVal = CDbl(DirectorBox.Value)
If IsNumeric(SnrBox.Value) Then checkVal = checkVal + CDbl(SnrBox.Value)
If IsNumeric(MngrBox.Value) Then checkVal = checkVal + CDbl(MngrBox.Value)
If IsNumeric(ResearcherBox.Value) Then checkVal = checkVal + CDbl(ResearcherBox.Value)
If checkVal <> 1# Then
    MsgBox "Values must amount to a total of 1"
    Exit Sub
End If
Sheets("Menu").Range("G13").Value = (Range("G9").Value * DirectorBox.Value) _
+ (Range("G10").Value * SnrBox.Value) + (Range("G11").Value * MngrBox.Value) _
+ (Range("G12").Value * ResearcherBox.Value)
Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

Note: the **"1#"** ensures that the literal "1" is also a `Double` type, the same as `checkVal`. Otherwise the interpreter would assume it's an `Integer`. [vba: what is 97.45 * 1# =?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301733/vba-what-is-97-45-1)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the answer!

I've got a lot to learn.

Comment: No probs. We've all got to start somewhere, and you've come to the right place!