# Why does Visual Basic Editor convert scientific notation to a number with # at the end?

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

I can't find any information on this:

I am initializing a variable and when I enter a number in scientific notation such as 8.45673E11, but it converts it to its standard form with a compound sign at the end 845673000000# - I would like to know if this is supposed to happen? Is there a setting that controls this automatic conversion? What does the compound sign indicate?

Thanks so much!
Lana

Comment: 8.45673E11 *is* 845673000000. No conversion is occurring. The `#` means that it is a double literal. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3301733/4996248

Comment: Have you tried `CDbl(ws.Cell().Value)?`

Comment: Hi John, yes I understand they are the same number but I am wondering why it's happening. Thanks for the post link. I'll check it out.

Comment: The point is that not only are they the same number -- they are the same datatype. It might be a problem if the VBE automatically converted a double or float to an integer type. It is somewhat annoying that it converts the number into a less readable form.

Comment: Yes, I agree! Also, I am wondering if you know why and under what circumstances it does this? Is it just automatic for any literal in scientific notation? I'm playing around and when I declare a variable as Double and try to initialize it with a number, it still adds the # at the end of the number - regardless if it's in scientific notation or typed as a standard number. Seems overkill-redundant?

Comment: If you type an integer value that's less than `2^31-1`, then the VBE won't be adding any *type hints* - the conversion (from `Long`, or from `Integer` if the literal value is less than `2^15-1`) will only happen later, when the expression is evaluated. With the type hint, conversion happens at compile-time - it's basically the compiler adding shortcuts for itself in the source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's happening because, when you type code in the VBE, *what you see is NOT what you get*.

The current line of code is just plain text: it's not understood as *code* until you hit ENTER or navigate away from that line. Then, several things happen under the hood:

- The VBE *parses* the current line of code, and determines if it can be compiled.

  - If it's an invalid statement, it either pops a "compile error" message box, or highlights the statement in red (depending on your VBE "compile on demand" settings).
- The valid code is compiled to P-Code instructions, and stored alongside the source in the host document - although it's all still only in memory at this point.
- The P-Code is translated back into VBA source, and the line of code you just entered is re-written in-place.

So when you write `Foo = 8.45673E11`, the VBE determines that the RHS of the assignment is a *double literal*, and compiles the corresponding P-Code instruction; when that instruction is translated back into VBA source code, it's "re-written" as an explicit *double literal*, `845673000000#` (`#` suffix being a *type hint* meaning "that's a `Double`") because P-Code doesn't care for the *representation* of a number (e.g. scientific notation), only the number itself; the *type hint* character is added so that the type is already known and doesn't need to be re-evaluated again next time the expression is compiled.

And when you write `Foo         =             8.45673E11`, you still get `Foo = 845673000000#`, because the P-Code doesn't care for *that* whitespace.

That's also why given `Public Foo As Double` if you type `foo = 123` you'll get `Foo = 123`, because the internal *symbol table* has `Foo` with an uppercase `F`.

Comment: Yay, it's Mathieu! Once again, thank you for a well-explained answer. Just one quick question: What does RHS stand for? :)

Comment: @GeekyFreaky that's *right-hand side*, sorry :) there's also LHS for *left-hand side* - these terms are often thrown in whenever an *expression* involving an *operator* is involved, to refer to each part of the expression. So an assignment expression like `foo = 42` has LHS `foo` and RHS `42`.

Comment: OMG, duh! I should have figured that out. hahaha Thanks.^^